# elements generated with javascript or jquery not being posted in mvc 5 c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

**collection of elements not being posted if generated with jquery or javascript**

i have read these articles 
[from codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/855577/List-of-Model-Object-Post-to-Controller-in-ASP-NET)
[from haaked](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/)
[from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600289/dynamically-rendering-and-posting-form-elements-in-asp-net-mvc-2/5600388#5600388)

all these solutions works only if elements are generated with razor but if i generate it with jquery or javascript data don't get posted even when names and ids are same and poperly generated with indexes 
**Html below is from page source.**

```
                     <div id="formGroup-123" class="frmgrp form-group">
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                            <label class="center-block">Name</label>
                                            <input maxlength="100" name="[0].kmpName" id="[0].kmpName" type="text" class="form-control kmpName">
                                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="[0].kmpName"
                                                  data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                            <label class="center-block">Email</label>
                                            <input maxlength="200" name="[0].kmpMail" id="[0].kmpMail" type="text" class="form-control kmpMail">
                                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="[0].kmpMail"
                                                  data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                            <label class="center-block">Phone</label>
                                            <input name="[0].kmpPhone" id="[0].kmpPhone" maxlength="15" type="text" class="form-control kmpPhone">
                                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="[0].kmpPhone"
                                                  data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                            <label class="center-block">&nbsp;</label>
                                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btnminus btn btn-warning" id="minus-123"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a>
                                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btnplus btn btn-warning" id="plus-123"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

i append multiple times this html block to a div thats not visible in page source however it can be seen using inspect element option in chrome browser.
i am posting below

```
<div class="frmgrp form-group" id="formGroup-2">
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                            <label class="center-block">Name</label>
                                            <input name="[2].kmpName" maxlength="15" type="text" class="form-control kmpName" id="[2].kmpName">
                                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="[2].kmpName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                            <label class="center-block">Email</label>
                                            <input name="[2].kmpMail" type="text" class="form-control kmpMail" id="[2].kmpMail">
                                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="[2].kmpMail" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                            <label class="center-block">Phone</label>
                                            <input name="[2].kmpPhone" type="text" class="form-control kmpPhone" id="[2].kmpPhone">
                                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="[2].kmpPhone" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                            <label class="center-block">&nbsp;</label>
                                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btnminus btn btn-warning" id="minus-2">
                                            <i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a>
                                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btnplus btn btn-warning" id="plus-2" style="display: none;"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
<div class="frmgrp form-group" id="formGroup-3">
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                            <label class="center-block">Name</label>
                                            <input name="[3].kmpName" maxlength="15" type="text" class="form-control kmpName" id="[3].kmpName">
                                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="[3].kmpName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                            <label class="center-block">Email</label>
                                            <input name="[3].kmpMail" type="text" class="form-control kmpMail" id="[3].kmpMail">
                                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="[3].kmpMail" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                            <label class="center-block">Phone</label>
                                            <input name="[3].kmpPhone" type="text" class="form-control kmpPhone" id="[3].kmpPhone">
                                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="[3].kmpPhone" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                            <label class="center-block">&nbsp;</label>
                                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btnminus btn btn-warning" id="minus-3">
                                            <i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a>
                                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btnplus btn btn-warning" id="plus-3" style="display: none;"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

at controller

```
public ActionResult Save(other_form_data m, IEnumerable<KMP> n)
    {
```

and kmp class is

```
    public class KMP
{
    public string kmpName { get; set; }
    public string kmpMail { get; set; }
    public string kmpPhone { get; set; }
}
```

at controller list fetches only one object(i.e. first row of controls [0].name,[0].email,[0].phone) dynamically values from dynamically appended elements are not being posted.
**plese guide me how to make it work with jquery generated controls**

Comment: Could you please share some [minimal, complete, and verifiable code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) relevant to your question.

Comment: double check name of controls. It should work no matter you created it using Razor or jQuery if you added elements correctly

Comment: It has nothing to do with Razor (Razor just generates the correct html, and your code is obviously not)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**name** attribute of `"formgroup-2"` and `"formgroup-3"` are not in correct order. That's why only one row of data is present.

Name of elements should be `[1].KmpName` for `formgroup-2`. Similarly it should be `[2].KmpName` for `formgroup-2`

As Stephen commented, this is not related to razor. The default mvc model binder will check all the elements in DOM or view page and binds or map it to the parameters in action method.

I haven't tested it, but this should work

```
    <div class="frmgrp form-group" id="formGroup-2">
         <div class="col-sm-3">
              <label class="center-block">Name</label>
              <input name="[1].kmpName" maxlength="15" type="text" class="form-control kmpName" id="[2].kmpName">
              <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="[2].kmpName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-3">
              <label class="center-block">Email</label>
              <input name="[1].kmpMail" type="text" class="form-control kmpMail" id="[2].kmpMail">
              <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="[2].kmpMail" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
               <label class="center-block">Phone</label>
               <input name="[1].kmpPhone" type="text" class="form-control kmpPhone" id="[2].kmpPhone">
               <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="[2].kmpPhone" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
           </div>
           <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label class="center-block">&nbsp;</label>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btnminus btn btn-warning" id="minus-2">
           <i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a>
           <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btnplus btn btn-warning" id="plus-2" style="display: none;"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
       </div>
</div>
<div class="frmgrp form-group" id="formGroup-3">
     <div class="col-sm-3">
          <label class="center-block">Name</label>
          <input name="[2].kmpName" maxlength="15" type="text" class="form-control kmpName" id="[3].kmpName">
          <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="[3].kmpName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-3">
          <label class="center-block">Email</label>
          <input name="[2].kmpMail" type="text" class="form-control kmpMail" id="[3].kmpMail">
          <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="[3].kmpMail" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-3">
          <label class="center-block">Phone</label>
          <input name="[2].kmpPhone" type="text" class="form-control kmpPhone" id="[3].kmpPhone">
           <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="[3].kmpPhone" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
           <label class="center-block">&nbsp;</label>
           <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btnminus btn btn-warning" id="minus-3">
           <i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a>
           <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btnplus btn btn-warning" id="plus-3" style="display: none;"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
      </div>
</div>
```

> **Note:** Your div elements use the id in correct order. If possible you can use that to correct the name attribute

Correct index can be added to element's name using following code

```
function addIndex(template) {
    var fieldNames = ['KmpName', 'KmpMail', 'KmpPhone'];
    var groupList = document.getElementsByClassName('frmgrp form-group');
    var index = parseInt(groupList[groupList.length - 1].id);
    var elements = $(template).find('input');
    for(var i =0, len = elements.length; i<length; i++)
        elements[i].name = '[' + index + '].' + fieldNames[i];
}
```

Comment: you are right i figured that out shortly, but how do i keep in order ,when i am dynamically adding and removing controls ,i am going to add those values in hidden feilds and then to form with correct name and order  before posting ,is there any better way you know?

Comment: you did not post the code for dynamically creating the elements through JavaScript. So I have no idea how you are generating name for the elements.

Comment: `  var template = jQuery.validator.format($.trim($("#template").val()));  kmpStatic.append(template(id)).show("slow");`

Comment: i am going to add those values in hidden feilds and then to form with correct name and order before posting to controller ,is there any better way you know?

Comment: it depends upon the situation. If I need to clear and recreate my entire page, I would go for post request. If only few elements need to be cleared, I would use ajax to post the data to controller and get appropriate response